# Reusing an IEnumerable<T> results in false result, e.g. on .Any()

Tags: .net, ienumerable, ienumerator, deferred-execution

I'm a little lost in deferred execution land:

I declare an instance of an IEnumerable implementing class

```
var wordEnumerable = new WordEnumerable(_text);
```

Then I iterate over it (the first word is "Lorem")

```
foreach (var word in wordEnumerable)
                    Console.WriteLine(word);
```

.. which is written to the console.

Now right thereafter in code I do a

```
Console.WriteLine(wordEnumerable.Any(w => w == "Lorem"));
```

.. and get a False as output.

Now If I put the .Any(..) part above the foreach loop I do get a true, however the loop does start with the second word.

My *expectation* was that .Net creates different runtime 'contexts' for each call to an IEnumerable and its underlying IEnumerator so they don't interfere... I wouldn't want to .Reset() it by hand in order to get a proper result?

What am I missing here?

**Update**:

- Link to IEnumerable implementation: https://gist.github.com/814352
- Link to IEnumerator implementation: https://gist.github.com/814354
- .. and finally the underlying text parser implementation: https://gist.github.com/814358

.. It is basically an IEnumerable that allows me to iterate over the words within a given string.

Comment: How does `WordEnumerable` implement `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Could you provide us with more info about WordEnumerable class? I have no problems with creating functionality you want using simple `List<string>`. And if collection was not changed between both code fragments, than your code should work as well, if WordEnumerable class works as expected.

Comment: There we go, added links to sources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation is correct - `Any` will call `GetEnumerator` again to get a fresh `IEnumerator<T>`. That should be fine *if* you've implemented `IEnumerable<T>` correctly. My guess is that your implementation of `WordEnumerable` is incorrect. Please post the code :)

What happens if you write:

```
Console.WriteLine("First");
foreach (var word in wordEnumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}

Console.WriteLine("Second");
foreach (var word in wordEnumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

? The other thing to check is that `WordEnumerable` implements `IEnumerable<string>` rather than `IEnumerable<object>`, otherwise your `==` check will be a reference identity check.

Comment: Oh my.. Thanks Jon! My bad.. I reused the Enumerator :) It's an IEnumerable<string>, so the == comparison does work fine.